# $A^2=-I_4$. Find possible values of minimal polynomial and characteristic polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, minimal-polynomials, cayley-hamilton

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{4\times 4}$ satisfy $$A^2=-I_4 .$$

> (a) Find possible values of $m_a$ (minimal polynomial) and $p_a$ (characteristic polynomial).
>
> (b) Find an example for A satisfying the condition.

Please help me approach the first question. I can assume (b) would immediately follow.

Comment: well, what are minimal and characteristic polynomial? In particular, what is the definition of the first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) The polynomial $f(x) = x^2 + 1$ vanishes at $A$. Therefore $m_A$ divides $f$. As $f$ is irreducible in $\mathbb R(x)$, $m_A=f$.

$p_A$ is a real polynomial. Its complex roots are the ones of $m_A$. And by Cayley-Hamilton theorem $m_A$ divides $p_A$. Hence $p_A=(x^2+1)^2$ as the degree of $p_A$ is equal to $4$.

(b) Now, consider a non-zero vector $u$. $(e_1 = u, e_2 = A \cdot u)$ is a linear independent family of vectors (see the note at the end of the post). You have $A \cdot e_1 = e_2$ and $A \cdot e_2 = A^2 \cdot u = -u = -e_1$. Therefore, the restriction of $A$ to the plane $(e_1, e_2)$ has for matrix:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.$$

Find a vector $e_3$ such that $(e_1, e_2,e_3)$ is linear independent. This is possible as your space dimension is equal to $4$. Then you'll be able to prove that $(e_1, e_2,e_3, A \cdot e_3)$ is also linear independent. The matrix of $A$ in this basis is 
$$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.$$

And we have proven that $A$ is always similar to such a matrix.

**Note:** proof that $(u, A \cdot u)$ are linear independent for $u \neq 0$.

Suppose that $\alpha u + \beta Au = 0$ with $\alpha$ and $\beta$ non-zero. Then applying $A$ on both sides of the equality $\alpha Au - \beta u = 0$. Multiply the first equality by $\alpha$, the second one by $\beta$ and substract both resulting equalities. You get $(\alpha^2 + \beta^2) u=0$. As $u$ is supposed to be non-zero, this implies $\alpha = \beta =0$.

Comment: please note that $A$ is over $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @AshuvHalim I missed that! I'll correct my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. How can you assume $\{u,Au\}$ are linear independent?

Comment: @AshuvHalim Suppose that $\alpha u + \beta Au = 0$. Then apply $A$ on both sides of the equality. You get $\alpha Au - \beta u = 0$. I let you go to the conclusion from there.

Comment: How do you conclude the $\alpha = \beta = 0$? I don't see it. sorry.

Comment: See my note at the end of the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77362/discussion-between-ashuv-halim-and-mathcounterexamples-net).

Answer (score 3):

The minimal polynomial is $m(x)=x^2+1$ because it's irreducible over $\mathbb{R}$. We know $m(A)=0$ and (due to Cayley-Hamilton) $p(A)=0,$ Since $\operatorname{deg}(p)=4,$ the characteristic polynomial is $p(x)=(x^2+1)^2=x^4+2x^2+1.$ Note, that the minimal polynomial and the characteristic polynomial share roots. That is, we cannot add roots to the characteristic polynomial that are not present in the minimal polynomial already.

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$
A^2 = -I\\
A^2 +I = 0
$$
and we direclty read off the polynomial $f(x) = x^2 + 1$, with $f(A) = 0$. Now you just need to figure out how the minimal and characteristic polynomials both relate to any given polynomial where $A$ is a root.

Comment: How do you know that this is the minimal polynomial?

Comment: @AshuvHalim I don't. It doesn't have to be. For instance, $x + i$ could be the minimal polynomial (assuming your matrices can have complex entries).

Comment: I should have noted that it's over $\mathbb{R}$. Sorry about that.

Comment: @AshuvHalim In that case, then $f$ _must_ be the minimal polynomial. But you would have to prove that by citing some theorem that relates the minimal polynomial to an arbitrary polynomial where $A$ is a root.

Comment: How can I find the characteristic polynomial then?

Comment: @AshuvHalim You can't find the characteristic polynomial. However, the problem isn't asking you to find the characteristic polynomial. "Find **possible values** of [...] $p_a$". It's asking you to find _all possible_ characteristic polynomials. And that's pretty easy, considering the [Cayley-Hamilton theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley–Hamilton_theorem), along with the theorem that _any polynomial of which $A$ is a root has the minimal polynomial as a factor_. You ought to know this already if you've been given this exercise.